Direct sum of free abelian group and quotient of abelian group by subgroup
I'm currently studying abelian groups in Kurosh's The Theory of Groups. I'm trying to understand the proof of the theorem:
Let $B \leqq A$  be abelian groups. If $A/B \cong C$ and $C$ is a free group, then $A\cong B \oplus C$
Kurosh gives a proof on page 144, though I don't quite follow these steps, and am looking for some more detail. I have looked at Manipulating quotients and direct sums of abelian groups, and the answer is certainly helpful, but still does not include a full proof. Both seem to suggest constructing a subgroup of generating elements, but I can't seem to figure out what the isomorphism would look like. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
From Kurosh:


You mean $C$ is a free abelian group, not $C$ is a free group.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

@DerekHolt yes, thank you!

Since $C$ is free abelian, $C = \mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$ for some index set $I$. For each $i \in I$, let $e_i \in \mathbb{Z}^{(I)} = C$ be the element that’s $1$ at $i \in I$ and $0$ everywhere else. Since $A/B = C$, we may pick $a_i \in A$ s.t. $a_i + B = e_i$. Then the desired isomorphism $\pi: B \oplus C \to A$ is given by,
$$\pi(b \oplus (z_i)_{i \in I}) = b + \sum_{i \in I} z_ia_i$$
It is clearly a group homomorphism. To see it is injective, note that $\pi(b \oplus (z_i)_{i \in I}) = 0$ implies $\varphi(\pi(b \oplus (z_i)_{i \in I})) = 0$ where $\varphi: A \to A/B = C$ is the natural quotient map. But $B = \ker(\varphi)$ and $\varphi(a_i) = e_i$, so $0 = \varphi(\pi(b \oplus (z_i)_{i \in I})) = \sum_{i \in I} z_ie_i$. Thus, $z_i = 0$ for all $i$. But then $0 = \pi(b \oplus (z_i)_{i \in I}) = b$. Therefore, $\ker(\pi) = \{0\}$.
For surjectivity, let $a \in A$ be arbitrary. Then $\varphi(a) = (z_i)_{i \in I}$ for some $(z_i)_{i \in I} \in \mathbb{Z}^{(I)} = C$. Thus, $b = a - \sum_{i \in I} z_ia_i$ satisfies that $\varphi(b) = \varphi(a) - \sum_{i \in I} z_ie_i = 0$, i.e., $b \in B$. Now by definition of $\pi$, we see that $a = \pi(b \oplus (z_i)_{i \in I})$, so $a \in \text{ran}(\pi)$, whence $\pi$ is surjective.

Thanks for this! Some of this is going a little over my head. Why can we pick $a_i \in I$ s.t. $a_i+B=e_i$? Are we considering $a$ to be elements of $A$ which are indexed by $I$? And what happens when we choose $\mathbb{N}$ as our index set? I've also edited my post to include Kurosh's explanation which I would really appreciate some pointers on!

@MathematicallyUnsound The first one is a typo. It should have been $a_i \in A$. It doesn’t matter what set is the index set - that is determined by what $C$ is, but the proof goes through regardless.

@MathematicallyUnsound Kurosh’s explanation that you added to your post is the same proof - my proof is just a more detailed explanation, is all.

Thanks, this makes more sense! Though I'm still a bit confused by surjectivity. $0=\varphi(b)=\varphi(a)-\sum_{i \in I} z_ie_i$ makes sense, but $\varphi$ is not necessarily injective, so how does this imply $b = a- \sum_{i \in I}z_i a_i$? I don't see how $\pi(b\oplus(z_i)_{i \in I})$ can be equal to the arbitrary $a \in A$.

@MathematicallyUnsound There is no implication, $b$ is defined to be $a - \sum_{i \in I} z_ia_i$, and $\varphi(b) = \varphi(a) - \sum_{i \in I} z_ie_i = 0$ is the consequence of this definition.

@MathematicallyUnsound By definition of $\pi$, $\pi(b \oplus (z_i){i \in I}) = b + \sum{i \in I} z_ia_i = a - \sum_{i \in I} z_ia_i + \sum_{i \in I} z_ia_i = a$.

Ah I see! Thank you for walking me through this!
